# I can't type to inputs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list which can be sortable. I'm using jQuery UI with widget, mouse, position, sortable addons.

CSS:

```
#sortable{
    width : 550px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#sortable li, #add {
    width : 550px;
    margin : 5px;
    padding : 5px;
    height : 50px;
}
#sortable li img.social-icon, #sortable li img.drag-cursor {
    width: 40px;
    height : 40px;
    float : left;
}
#sortable li img.social-icon {
    margin-right : 5px;
}
#sortable li img.drag-cursor {
    margin-left : 5px;
    cursor : move;
}
#sortable li input {
    height:40px;
    width:450px;
    line-height: 45px;
    float:left;
}
#add {
    cursor : pointer;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 45px;
}
.ui-state-highlight { height: 50px; line-height: 50px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dash-wrapper">
    <ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default">
            <img src="images/social/twitter.png" class="social-icon" />
            <input type="text" value="textt" name="user-media-link[]" class="user-media-link">
            <input type="hidden" name="social-media-type" value="1">
            <img src="images/drag.png" class="drag-cursor">
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">
            <img src="images/social/facebook.png" class="social-icon" />
            <input type="text" value="textt" name="user-media-link[]">
            <input type="hidden" name="social-media-type" value="1">
            <img src="images/drag.png" class="drag-cursor">
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">
            <img src="images/social/rss.png" class="social-icon" />
            <input type="text" value="textt" name="user-media-link[]">
            <input type="hidden" name="social-media-type" value="1">
            <img src="images/drag.png" class="drag-cursor">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="ui-state-default" onCLick="addNewSocial(); return false;" id="add">ADD</div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    });
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});

function addNewSocial() {
    $("#sortable").append('<li class="ui-state-default"><img src="" width="100" height="100" /> <input type="text" value="textt" name="user-media-link[]"><input type="hidden" name="social-media-type" value="1"></li>');
}
```

It's working very well, but I can't type anything to inputs. I can reach them only via TAB button. When I click them, nothing happens. You can see a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/teknoblogo/KbBnu/).

I was read all questions which related with this question, but i couldn't find right answer.

```
W3 Validation is OK 
There isn't any error on Firebug 
Operation System : Ubuntu 11.04 
Browser : Firefox
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This happens because you have `$("#sortable").disableSelection();`. Remove it and will work ok.

http://jsfiddle.net/KbBnu/1/

Comment: I can't find the thread with my solution, but someone had the same problem when using `disableSelection()`. A workaround could be if you bind the `mousedown` event to your inputs and call `stopPropagation()` like this: `$('input[type="text"]').mousedown(function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); });` This way you keep the benefit of `disableSelection()` too.

Comment: @DarthJDG, You rock... For me, removing `disableSelection()` was not the solution at all. But your solution really worked like a charm. Thank you very much!!

Comment: I'll be glad if you explain why this happen. Anyway, it works like a charm. Thank you so much for this help.

Answer (score 3):

If would like to prevent text selection but continue to use inputs at the same time, you should try this

```
$('body *').not(':has(input)').not('input').disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
$( "#sortable_container_id input").click(function() { $(this).focus(); });
```

and replace `sortable_container_id` with the id of the element that is the container of all "sortable" elements.