# Input text field does not work in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, text, input

I'm creating some application in jQuery UI, and I've noticed that if I create input text field with a JS, it doesn't work at all. Here is the part of code that creats this field.
I have a variable like this:

```
var AddNewDepartment = "<br /><br />\
<form>\
<table class='AddNewDepartment-table'>\
<td>\
Department Name:<span style='color: red'>*</span>&nbsp;\
<input type='text' name='departmentName' id='departmentName' class='expanded-input-    text' />\
<input type='button' name='save' id='save' onclick='createDepartment()' Value='Save' class='newDepartment-submit' />\
<input type='button' name='cancel' Value='Cancel' class='newDepartment-submit'  />\
</td>\
</table>\
</form>\
";
```

Later I'm creating this form with jQuery
    $("#someId").html(AddNewDepartment);

Comment: Try `$("#someId").val(AddNewDepartment);` since it's an input.

Comment: It worked fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/UcHQt/ with the latest version of (14.0.1) FF...

Comment: I found the solution! Problem was with jquery sortable function
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083009/i-cant-type-to-inputs