# Input text and button field does not work in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, widget

I am working on some application that use JQUERY widgets. In that widget there is some input field like text, textarea and button. I can only access these field through TAB, but with mouse click direct it can't be done. This app works fine on Chrome.
Simple html with these fields works, but when I add those fields in js file, and then call those file in other js file, those fields doesn't work in Firefox.

This is js file:

```
var AddNewDepartment = "<br />\
<form>\
<table class='AddNewDepartment-table'>\
<tr>\
<td>\
Department Name:<span style='color: red'>*</span>&nbsp;\
<input type='text' name='departmentName' id='departmentName' class='expanded-input-text' />\
<input type='button' name='save' id='save' onclick='createDepartment()' Value='Save' class='newDepartment-submit' />\
<input type='button' name='cancel' Value='Cancel' class='newDepartment-submit'  />\
</td>\
</tr>\
</table>\
</form>\
";
```

Please, I need help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

From your post it seems you're appending the form to DOM dynamically i.e after page load. In that you need delegate event handling for them.

You can try with `.on()` like following:

```
$(document).on('click', 'form AddNewDepartment-table input,form AddNewDepartment-table textarea', function() {

 // your code

});
```

For delegate event handling the syntax of `.on()` is:

```
$(StaticParent).on( eventName, targets, handlerFunction );
```

Here `StaticParent` means the DOM element which is not dynamic and belong to DOM at page load. `eventName` may be space separated for multiple event binding.

Comment: I am using JQUERY widget, and all pages are defined in javascript. They are invited inside a another js page. In main index.html file all js files are included. I am using jquery dropable, sortable and draggable. Problem occur when a widget needs to be overlaid on the dashboard and to insert the text in its input field. I need mouse functionality.

Comment: I found the solution!
Problem was with jquery sortable function
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083009/i-cant-type-to-inputs